# Error With service endpoint in wcf https ssl. Cannot find base address that matches scheme http for the end point with binding WebHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, ssl, https

i have the following code in my server

```
<services>
  <service name="ME.Streets.WebGateway.DuplexService.DuplexService"
     behaviorConfiguration="sb">
    ....
    <endpoint
        address=""
        binding="webHttpBinding"
        behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBehavior"
        contract="ME.Streets.WebGateway.DuplexService.Interface.IPolicyRetriever"/>
     ....
    <host>
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="https://localhost:10201" />
    </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

I have been switching the silverlight application over to HTTPS with SSL and WCF, but if i run my server, i recieved the following error

```
- System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches
 scheme http for the endpoint with binding WebHttpBinding. Registered base address     
 schemes are [https].
```

I am highly unsure of where this error is coming from.  Do i have to install a https `<baseaddress>` node within the `<service>` node?

Comment: are you using a self signed certificate?

Comment: i am indeed! it is called localhost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed!

Changed the endpoint to this (added bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding"):

```
<services> .....
        <endpoint
            address=""
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="webHttpEndpointBehavior"
            bindingConfiguration="webHttpsBinding"
            contract="ME.Streets.WebGateway.DuplexService.Interface.IPolicyRetriever">
        </endpoint>
......
</services>
```

And the new binding configuration is as follows:

```
<bindings>....
    <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpsBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
......
</bindings>
```

This gives the end point a binding to a http binding that specifies which was to transport the information and the type of credentials that connected users must have